# Solutions of a congruence: $x^2 \equiv 429 \pmod{563}$

Tags: number-theory

How can I prove that $$x^2 \equiv 429 \pmod{563}$$

has $22$ solutions?  I know I can probably use the Legendre symbol but I am not sure how to do so.

This question is from Elements of number theory  By Ivan Matveevič Vinogradov.

Comment: $563$ is prime. It can have thus maximum $2$ solutions.

Comment: It can have at most $2$ solutions and $100^2 \equiv 429 \pmod{563}$.

Comment: hmm okay thanks

Comment: I don't see a typo in the book at Google Books; it says "Using the Jacobi symbol, find the number of solutions of the congruences: ... $\beta$) $x^2 \equiv 429 \pmod {563}$."

Comment: in the solutions manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's a typo in the book.

As $563$ is prime, the equation can only have $2$ solution at most.

As Marvis observed in a comment, one solution is $100$, and then the other is $-100\equiv 463$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (from Ramanujan) $\rm\  mod\ 563\!:\ 429\equiv 992\equiv 16\cdot 62\equiv 16\cdot 625\equiv 4^2\cdot 25^2\! \equiv 100^2.\: $ Hence, $\rm\:mod\ p=563\!:\,\ x^2\!-429\equiv x^2-100^2.\:$ Thus prime $\rm\:p\mid(x\!-\!100)(x\!+\!100)\:\Rightarrow\:p\mid x\pm 100,\:$ hence $\rm\:x\equiv \pm100\ \ (mod\ p).$

Of course one could also quadratic reciprocity too, e.g. Euler's criterion, or Legendre symbols, etc. But that would be less fun.